# How to trigger a Chrome extension, content-script for a given hash in the URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest, hashtag, content-script

My matches scheme:

```
"content_scripts" : [
 {
   "matches" : [
     "https://stackoverflow.com/questions#epic*"
   ],
   "js" : ["silly.js"]
 }
],
```

So if the user went to a webpage (like https://stackoverflow.com/questions) then added `#epic` it would go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions#epic but would have `#epic` on the end of the URL, which would activate the content script `silly.js`.

That's what's supposed to happen, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think matching against the `hash` is supported. You could always match against `http://stackoverflow.com/questions*` and then check for the hash in your script instead.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but I didnt know for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See [Content scripts, Match Patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).
Match patterns do not operate on the [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax) portion of a URL.

To restrict a content script to a given hash, use [the `include_globs` and/or `exclude_globs` properties](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs).

For example, in this case you might use:

```
"content_scripts" :     [ {
    "matches" :         [
        "*://stackoverflow.com/questions/*"
    ],
    "include_globs" :   ["*#epic*"],
    "js" :              ["silly.js"]
} ],
```